# Slots in python inheritance

Tags: python-2.7

I understand that once we add `__slots__`  we are restricting the attributes that can be used in a class, although the primary purpose is to save memory of the created instance (by not storing it in the `__dict__` )

But i don't fully understand how  `__slots__` behave when inherited.

```
class Vector(object): 
    __slots__ = ('name','age')
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.age = None


class VectorSub(Vector):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.age = None
        self.c = None

a = Vector()  #  
b = VectorSub()
print dir(a)
# __slots__ defined and no __dict__ defined here, understandable

print dir(b) 
# Both __dict__ and __slot__ defined.
#So __slots__ is inherited for sure.


print a.__dict__ #AttributeError: has no attribute '__dict__, understandable
print b.__dict__ #{'c': None} ... How?
print b.name # Works, but why?  'name' not in b,__dict__
```

This is when i am confused. First off, if `__slots__` is inherited, there shouldn't even be a `__dict__` in "b" since the instance attributes cannot be stored in a dict - by the definition of slots.  Also why is that `name` and `age`  are not stored in b.`__dict__` ?

Comment: Also this is covered in the docs for slots - "The action of a `__slots__` declaration is limited to the class where it is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a `__dict__` unless they also define `__slots__` (which must only contain names of any additional slots)."

Answer (score 2):

`__slots__` not only saves memory, but also has **faster access**. (accessing tuple instead of a dict)

Taken from python's `__slots__` doc:

> The action of a **slots** declaration is limited to the class where it is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a **dict** unless they also define **slots** (which must only contain names of any additional slots).

So `__slots__` is inherited, but a `__dict__` attribute is also created for subclasses **unless** explicity define a `__slots__` object in the subclass

There are few other notes worth mentioning, check [**slots** doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots)